# rspec setup for integration tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, integration-testing

I want to set up some database state for integration tests.  My basic setup looks like this:

```
describe "some behaviour" do
  before(:each) do
    <setup some mock objects with stubs>

    <call the database set up script>
  end
end
```

- Setting up the mocks naturally belongs in a `before(:each)`, the examples depend on the mocks.
- The database setup script is slow, so I only want to call it once.
- Part of the process being integration tested is the database setup script.  While I can change the script to make it easier to test, I can't remove its dependency on the state of the mocks.
- The database setup must be called after the setup for the mocks because it depends on them.  E.g. some of the mocks return identifiers which the database setup script needs to put in database records.

So really I want to put the database setup in a `before(:all)`.  `before(:all)` causes the setup to be run **before** the `before(:each)`, so I can't see how to meet all the requirements.

I tried to split out the setup of the mocks into a helper function, which I called as the first call in both the `before(:all)` and `before(:each)`. rspec doesn't allow creation of doubles in `before(:all)` blocks, so this didn't work.

Is there any way to run the slow database setup only once, but still have the mocks available?

Comment: Mocking is cheap. Why not put Your slow DB config inside :all block, mocking inside :each.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons, I already tried that, as I said in my question.

Comment: "some of the mocks return identifiers which the database setup script needs to put in database records." - try doing vice versa. Adjust mocks to records returned from DB.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons, unfortunately I can't.  The database setup script is the part of the system being tested, and its role is to process inputs to generate a certain state.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why not do it in the spec_helper, much like one would utilize database cleaner.   `config.before(:all) { }`. Put that in the Rspec.configure block. Not something i've tried, so no idea how well it works.